# How to stop scrolling ontouchscreen in custom view

Tags: android, scroll, touch

I have code for a custom class that allows 2dscrolling... sort of.  Everything works to my liking, except one thing.  Horizontal scrolling (horizontalscrollview is nested in this view)  still stops when the screen is tapped.  However, vertical scrolling is no longer stopped when the screen is touch.  How can I make this happen?  Should I add the code to my customscrollingview or to the java for the activity?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class ParentScrollView extends ScrollView {
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ParentScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new YScrollDetector());
    setFadingEdgeLength(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if( mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)&super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)){
        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}

// Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction  
class YScrollDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float     
    distanceY) {
        if(Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{ 
switch (ev.getAction()) 
   {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: this.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); 
   break; 
   } 
   return super.onTouchEvent(ev); }
```

and it is much more workable now.  The scrolling is much less likely to act as though it has been "flung".